# Dynamic form validation using angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, validation, angular, angular2-forms

I am working on angular 2 application and creating the form fields dynamically(using json) in a subsection template. 
I wanted to disable submit button when the form is invalid.

```
<h1>Form Validation</h1>
<div >
<form #loginForm="ngForm">
    <subsection [question]="fieldsData"></subsection>
    <button  type="submit"  [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Sub section as it follows

```
<div *ngFor="let data of question">
<label> {{data.displayName}}</label>
<input type="data.dataType" name="data.fieldId" [(ngModel)]="data.fieldValue" required name="data.fieldId" #name="ngModel">
<div *ngIf="name.errors && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div [hidden]="!name.errors.required">
        Name is required
    </div>     
</div>
<br><br>
```

I have a requirement where submit button should be enabled after all the required fields are filled

Created plunker link [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/iug0RLvyp2hjMue5Wj5F?p=preview)

Comment: @GabrieleB-David form fields are loaded in the subsection template. I am passing fields as input to the template

Comment: I believe it's because your inputs are in a child component. You have to give the parent component a way of seeing if all the fields are filled. Why not put the whole form in one component?

Comment: @GabrieleB-David you are correct. (assume) i am using reusable component to create the form fields. So parent form element not having hold on child form elements?

Comment: Then you could use an `@Output` event that triggers when all the forms are filled in the child.

Comment: maybe this answer will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980344/angular-2-form-level-validation-using-components

Comment: @Pengyy Thank you so much. Will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your plunkr I think you'd be better served using a [reactive form](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html) rather than the template driven form approach you have described, as you are defining your form fields in a model anyway (the `fieldsData` array defined in `AppComponent`).

The current template approach isn't giving you the validation behaviour you want as the `input` fields in the sub-component are not participating in the wider form - if you debug `loginForm.value` you will see that the name fields are not part of the form - meaning that if you submit the form, the form will not contain the data entered in those fields.

An alternative is to make the sub-component participate in the form by implementing `ControlValueAccessor` as described [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html) but this adds complexity you may not need.

A simpler way would be (1) use reactive forms or (2) don't use a nested subsection component at all.

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm">

   <div *ngFor="let data of fieldsData">
      <label> {{data.displayName}}</label>
      <input type="data.dataType"  [(ngModel)]="data.fieldValue" required       [name]="data.fieldId" #name="ngModel">
      <div *ngIf="name.errors && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div [hidden]="!name.errors.required">
              {{data.displayName}} is required
          </div>     
      </div>
      </div>
   <button  type="submit"  [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid">Submit</button>

   Form contains: {{loginForm.value | json }}

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**question.component.html**

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm">
<div *ngFor="let data of question">
    <label> {{data.displayName}}</label>
    <input type="data.dataType"  [(ngModel)]="data.fieldValue" required name="data.fieldId" #name="ngModel">
    <div *ngIf="name.errors && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div [hidden]="!name.errors.required">
            {{data.displayName}} is required
        </div>     
    </div>
    <br><br>
</div>
<button  type="submit"  [disabled]="loginForm.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The above disables the submit button you can use the above to activate using *ngIf. You can also use the above as !loginForm.valid.

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>Form Validation</h1>
    <subsection [question]="fieldsData"></subsection>
```

Comment: @PraveenMP I updated my answer I see that this was not working . when using !loginForm.invalid the button used to disable but due to reverse condition it was disabling the button completely even after filling the form I dont know what is causing it. But the above works if you move your forms section completely inside one component and move that comonent to another.

Comment: Yes i have understood the way you are implemented and it works. But i don't want to keep  subsection code in the main component.